# Nested range query in Lucene.NET

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I am facing an issue with search with ranges in Lucene.NET. I have an employee with MinRate and Maxrate as 2 fields in the document. I have to search for employees where my input again is a range with minvalue and maxvalue. So I have to filter all the employees, whose range overlaps with in the search range. If it does not then, it should not return the results.

My Fields are MINRATE, MAXRATE
Input fields or minval and maxval

I am following the approach, where I check for minval in between MINRATE and MAXRATE - (+MINRATE:[0000 TO minval] +MAXRATE:[minval  TO 1000])

Then maxval between MINRATE and MAXRATE - (+MINRATE:[0000 TO maxval] +MAXRATE:[maxval TO 1000])

Now I have see if either one of the query is true then it the results have to be displayed. Also as I have other filters also, when combined with them, overall rate condition has to be mandatory.

Any help how to approach this will be really helpful.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question, but are you looking for a query that detects when minval and maxval are between MINRATE and MAXRATE?

Comment: @goalie7960 : Yes, I want results where at least minval or maxval is between MINRATE and MAXRATE